# POST Methods not working on rewrite NGINX

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am having trouble on how to get url rewrite using nginx.
I have a configured a server to rewrite all request to /api to a different application on a different port
here is my config

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5021;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

When i try to make a curl request using **GET** it succeeds and gets the data.
but when i do **POST** its serving bad request

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost/api/auth/forgotpassword" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"email\":\"someemail@gmal.com\"}"
```

Heres what i got from the logs

```
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 http keepalive handler
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 malloc: 000055D139AF11D0:1024
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 recv: eof:1, avail:1
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 recv: fd:12 0 of 1024
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [info] 15411#15411: *3 client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 close http connection: 12
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 event timer del: 12: 50648776
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 reusable connection: 0
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 free: 000055D139AF11D0
2020/08/11 13:09:17 [debug] 15411#15411: *3 free: 000055D139AF07C0, unused: 136
```

Comment: Did you already examine the log? Enable logging with         error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

Comment: I will try this one. I setup the log to notice

Comment: I Added the erro logs

Comment: Does it show something useful? If the nginx gives you the "bad request" response you mentioned in your question you should see some releevant logs in your /var/log/nginx/error.log. If not you can configure a custom log_format, that will log the post request and other interesting data.

Comment: running sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error_log.log it shows the update above. Im new to nginx

Comment: @LukasRäpple 
2020/08/11 13:25:23 [debug] 15620#15620: *9 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/api/auth/login"
2020/08/11 13:25:23 [debug] 15620#15620: *9 http upstream request: "/api/auth/login?"

Comment: I think its not copying the whole url

Comment: You could also try to change proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade' to proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection

Comment: @LukasRäpple please post an answer your comment saves the day

Comment: Ok, i did. Did the new header solve the problem?

Comment: @LukasRäpple yes mate. It works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing in your config:

```
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
```

To:

```
proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
```

Comment: Saved me a ton of time. I owe you a cup of coffee

Comment: GPT-4 get's this one wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that application prefers the URL's to start with "/api" too?  As in:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5021/api;
    ....
```

Comment: I already tried this one and it didn't work.